# Creating buffer in SYCL for 2D std::vector

Tags: c++, sycl

What is the correct way to create a 2D `std::vector` buffer in SYCL?
I have a template function which receives arguments as shown below:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void MatrixMulParallelNaive(queue& q, 
    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a,
    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& b,
    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& c){ 
    
    // Is this a correct way?
    buffer<T, 2> a_buf(a.data(), range<2>{a.size(), a[0].size()})
    buffer<T, 2> b_buf(b.data(), range<2>{b.size(), b[0].size()})
    buffer<T, 2> c_buf(c.data(), range<2>{c.size(), c[0].size()})
    
    /* ... */
}
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are 2D `std::vector`s

I have been able to implement buffers for 2D C-style arrays, but I've tried multiple docs and answers, but none seem to match this specific usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `vector<vector<T>>` doesn't create a contiguous block of memory. You need to use `vector<T>` and interpret it as a two dimensional block of data.

Comment: Do you mean I flatten the 2D vector and access as a linear block of memory?

Comment: @KaranShan yeah. `data(x,y) := vec[x+y*cols]`. You should also checkout what happens with the stride. Normally images and the like have height, width, and stride as parameters and thus I believe `buffer<T,2>` should have one as well.